# Oracle: How can I track the progress of an index rebuild?

Tags: oracle, index, monitoring

How can I track the progress of a command such as this?

```
alter index myindex rebuild reverse online;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should Query the V$SESSION_LONGOPS

```
select ops.OPNAME, ops.TIME_REMAINING,ops.start_time
from v$session_longops ops
where ops.sid=&your_sid
and ops.serial#=&your_serial
and time_remaining>0;
```

If the index rebuild is parallel, than you you must find the parallel slaves that do the work.
This can be done by querying the V$PX_SESSION. Your session that issued the 'alter index' statement is the query coordinator

```
select ops.OPNAME, ops.TIME_REMAINING,ops.start_time
from v$px_session par, v$session_longops ops
where par.qcsid=&your_sid
and par.qcserial#=&your_serial
and ops.sid=par.sid
and ops.serial#=par.serial#
and ops.time_remaining>0;
```

But an index creation consists of more than one longops (scan the table, sort the data,...)

Comment: if you're using an IDE, you can usually browse sessions and see the v$longops status visually